# mysql service is stopping and not restarting despite Restart=always

Tags: mysql, restart

I've had a site running on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 server for about 5 months without issues.

I've recently moved two other smallish sites to that server.

Suddenly, I'm waking up to downtime reports on all 3 sites.

The issue is Error Establishing Database Connection.

Running the following fixes it...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

The original value within

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysqld.service
```

was

```
Restart=on-failure
```

but after reading [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples), I've changed this to

```
Restart=always
```

I'd made this change 3 days ago, yet I've woken up to the same issue today. I've had to run...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

despite

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysqld.service
```

being set to

```
Restart=always
```

I came across [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054839/mysql-service-always-crashes), but the answer had a minus 1 against up.

If anyone can help with some further suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

The content of the service file...

```
# MySQL systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PIDFile=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
TimeoutSec=600
Restart=always
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
LimitNOFILE=5000
```

[View journalctl file here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzfvwbzrwnxs4o9/journalctl.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Please edit your question to a) use proper formatting ([help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)) b) add the `systemd` service file c) add some information from `journalctl -u <your_mySQL.service>`

Comment: @Fiximan a) Thanks for formatting tip b) file contents now included (still not sure of what's is and isn't safe to post) c) I wasn't aware of journalctl but will be sure to check next time. I'm guessing posting the contents in a Dropbox link isn't ideal, as it will likely break in the future. If I'm to post in the question, is there a guide to what would be a sensible amount to post?

Comment: @Fiximan I've searched for "mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'" based on the information within journalctl and I found [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-stopped-and-it-can-t-be-restart) The issue here seems to relate to memory. I have an alert set up for if memory usage goes above 80%, which I haven't had any warning of. I've looked at the mysql log, as per that post and I can also see "Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool" so maybe my issue is memory. If so, why would memory be an issue if I've not gone above 80%?

Comment: 80% system memory? Might just be that mysql tries to allocate memory but there is not enough free memory to allocate. Hard to tell. What exit code do you get? (should be looking like `code=exited, status=XXX/EXEC` where XXX=exit code). Compare to here: https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#id-1.20.8  Have you set limits in the mysql config file?

Comment: The 80% alert was based on the information [here](https://spinupwp.com/hosting-wordpress-yourself-server-monitoring-caching/).
The exit code appears to be 1... `code=exited status=1` which according to the link provided, means "Generic failure or unspecified error." A nice descriptive error message! :D

Comment: My server has been set up using [SpinupWP](https://spinupwp.com/), so a lot of the settings have been configured using this service. My [config file](https://bit.ly/2qL97M3) doesn't appear to contain much but has two include directories. The conf.d directory contains [mysql.cnf](https://bit.ly/33GXRit) and [mysqldump.cnf](https://bit.ly/2KgItBw) and the mysql.conf.d directory contains [mysqld.cnf](https://bit.ly/2qHVwFt) and [mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf](https://bit.ly/2rvGjYe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067577/mysql-will-not-restart

Also:
1. Show sql.log
2. Why sql crashed after add new site, maybe they have errors? 
3. Check work sql without new site.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I thought I'd best sort my question out before tackling solutions. My problem isn't currently as severe as the question you posted a link to. 1) [sql.log sample here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3a8vyfnohdhddbm/mysql%20log.txt?dl=0) 2) As you can see from my comments to Fiximan, it's looking like a memory issue. Just struggling to understand why an alert wouldn't get triggered. 3) I'd like to investigate other options a bit more before migrating the two other sites back to their original server.

Comment: Djonston, thank you. If your error with memory, maybe you can test this variable?           Into /etc/my.cnf innodb-buffer-pool-size = xxxM.                systemctl restart mysql? Also, you use deprecation option, and have few another problem.

Comment: Slightly confused... I think you're suggesting I try adding `innodb-buffer-pool-size = xxxM` to my sql config file and mess around with the xxx value to see if anything helps. I've been reading [this link](https://bit.ly/36Vt3wm) but looking at my config files (see comments to Fiximan), I don't appear to already have a value for this. `key_buffer_size = 16M` within mysqld.cnf is the only thing that seems close. Based on what I've read, I should try adding  `innodb-buffer-pool-size = 128M` to mysqld.cnf but not sure where. I'm guessing close to `# * InnoDB` would be a good idea.

Comment: FYI: The server currently has 1CPU and 1GB RAM and I'm aware that an upgrade will be needed, but I want to avoid increasing resources that will mask an underlying problem. I'm also not ignoring your comment about "deprecation options" but having used SpinupWP to configure the server, tackling "deprecation options" will be another task altogether.